# Multiple SSL's on one farm on Azure with one IP

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Windows Azure hosted environment:

1 x SharePoint 2013 on Server 2012
1 x SQL Server 2012 Standard on Server 2012

At this point we have multiple HNSC's running using a wildcard SSL, but we have a need to have a HNSC with a unique domain name not associated with our company.

I am fully aware of the limitations of IIS, and in any other situation I would just add another IP address, however Azure does have that capability.

I am trying to determine if it is possible to load the SSL cert into a proxy, use the wildcard to encrypt traffic between SharePoint and the proxy, and then using the unique SSL from the proxy to the end user.

Or is there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved with IIS 8, Server 2012 R2, and SharePoint 2013 SP1. You create a new host named web app on port 443 using the new URL, install the SSL certificate, and check the server name indication box in IIS. Very straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

If however you are stuck with this architecture, then you can look at deploying Kemp Load balancer in front of your SharePoint / SharePoint Web Front End Cloud Service. It is free to use within Azure and quite well documented on the deployment etc.

You can do SSL offloading and also all the funkiness of a Layer 7, Layer 4 Load balancer.

http://kemptechnologies.com/au/white-papers/loadmaster-azure/ document shows the steps involved in deploying it.

I have deployed a medium sized SharePoint farm for a public facing site that uses these guys. Brilliant support!